# How to restrict insecure http requests in play framework

Tags: playframework

How do I restrict insecure http connection in play frame work? If it is spring boot I would do something like below

http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/text").requiresSecure().and().authorizeRequests()

Comment: Do you only want to do this for specific endpoints? If you would like to do this application-wide, this is documented here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfiguringHttps#Turning-HTTP-off

Comment: I have no idea what the spring boot commands do. Maybe you should explain what it is you are after.

Comment: Hi cbley,Thanks for responding. I am actually trying to restrict insecure http calls hitting my server  that is hosted on PCF that way only secure connections are made and insecure connections are declined

Comment: Hey @ReganKoopmans, I tried making the http property changes in my application.conf file but that did not work for me though

Comment: You could also create a https redirect quite easily https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/RedirectHttpsFilter